# Using command-line arguments in J

Tags: argv, j

I know that `ARGV` represents the arguments. Can I type arguments after the filename in `jqt.exe` or does that only work in `jconsole.exe`. Executing the code regarding `ARGV` given in the J docs crashes J on my Win 10. An example would be welcome.
I tried out `0 ". > ,. 2 }. ARGV` from an earlier question on SO, but am not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `jqt` and `jconsole` read the command line arguments and box them:

```
jqt script.ijs arg1 arg2


  ARGV
┌───┬──────────┬────┬────┐
│jqt│script.ijs│arg1│arg2│
└───┴──────────┴────┴────┘


  2}. ARGV
┌────┬────┐
│arg1│arg2│
└────┴────┘

  ] x =: > 3 { ARGV
arg2
```

example script:

```
$ cat script.ijs
x =: ". every 2 }. ARGV                                                                                                                
echo +/ x 

$ jqt script.ijs 1 2 3
6
```